# validation on field

Tags: office-365

In office 365, Is it possible to write column validation to check if the entered text is number and include decimal less than 25?

I have a column named marks of type Single line of text. I would like to be able to stop the user if he or she enters the text other than number and greater than 25.

By the way, I don't want to have my column as Number; this solution t doesn't work for my design because i need to check the value is empty or not for workflows.

I tried using formula `=ISNUMBER([My Column]+0)` but the problem is I need to get the document from another library through workflows by this method it is showing error.

Comment: Is client-side validation an option here? JavaScript/jQuery?

Answer (score 2):

Add a script editor web part and paste the following pseudo code

```
var x=document.getElementById("MyColumnId").value;
if (isNaN(x)) 
{
    alert("Must input numbers");
}
else
{
    x.split(".");
    if(x[1] > 25)
    {
        alert("Decimal must be less than 26");
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```